# Angry Birds scores did not transfer from iPhone to iPad

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I uploaded all my Angry Bird games, Star Wars, Bad Piggies, etc., from my iPhone to my iPad. The games uploaded fine but all my hard earned scores are gone. Do I need to replay levels to get to where I was?

Answer (score 2):

Although the developer didn't write the code to keep your progress in sync, you can manually move the save files and settings from identical versions of the App - sometimes even from iOS to a computer version of the game.

In a nutshell, you'll need software to poke into the Application's saved files - so you'll need a PC or Mac or to jailbreak both your iOS devices.

Second, you'll learn what files and check the versions and move the files.

Worst case, you crash the new empty version of the app, and delete it and try to move the scores a second time.

There are many tutorials on this. Our site [and others](http://www.macworld.com/article/1156802/angry_birds_saved.html) have information on using [PhoneView on the Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=phoneview), and a game site has a very well done tutorial that I will link below:

- http://www.angrybirdsnest.com/how-to-transfer-angry-birds-progress-between-ios-devices/

Good luck - you'll learn more about how apps work, and hopefully not have to replay all those levels!

Comment: You don't have to jailbreak, at least with iFunBox!

Comment: @Ryccardo You are totally correct - Either a tool to read files or a jailbreak is needed, but any tool that reads iOS files when the device is connected over USB will allow you to inspect the save files and copy/move them appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

A few months ago Rovio updated the original "Angry Birds" and "Angry Birds HD" for iOS  with the ability to sync progress between devices. Unfortunately none of the sequels have been updated with this ability yet. According to the [TUAW article](http://www.tuaw.com/2013/07/19/rovio-account-lets-angry-birds-fans-sync-games-across-devices/), the ability to sync other games is  coming.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official Angry Birds site, there's no way to back up the Angry Birds score on one iPhone and transfer it to another iPhone. AngryBirdsNest you can back up Angry Birds scores via using ifunbox (a third party tool).

This could also answer your question: [Save Angry Birds progress on iOS and transfer scores to another iPhone](http://www.copytrans.net/blog/save-angry-birds-progress-on-ios-and-transfer-scores-to-another-iphone/)